# dimension of column space and null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

I am trying to answer a series of questions given the dimension of a matrix.

Suppose that $A$ is a $6 \times 12$ matrix.

**The column space is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. What is n?**

$n = 6$ because there can only be 6 pivot columns.

**The null space is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$. What is m?**

$m = 12$? Not so sure about this question.

**Is it possible to have rank = 4, dimension of null space = 8?**

$rank \leq min(m,n)$ for $m \times n$ matrix,

rank + nullity = number of columns.

It is possible.

**Is it possible to have rank = 8, dimension of null space = 4?**

rank + nullity = number of columns

but $rank \nleq min(m,n)$.

It is not possible.

Are my answers valid for the three questions that I answered?

I am a bit confused with the second question.

Any help would be great.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

> **The column space is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. What is n?**
>
> $n = 6$ because there can only be 6 pivot columns.

Your answer is technically correct, but misleading.  I would say the following: the column-space is a subspace that contains the columns of $A$.  Because the columns of $A$ each have $6$ entries, an element of the column space has $6$ entries which is to say that the column space is a subspace of $\Bbb R^6$.

> **The null space is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$. What is m?**
>
> $m = 12$? Not so sure about this question.

Your answer is correct; here's a reason.  The nullspace of $A$ is the set of column-vectors ($k \times 1$ vectors for some $k$) $x$ satisfying $Ax = 0$.  However, in order for $Ax$ to make sense, the "inner dimensions" of $m \times n, k \times 1$ need to match, which is to say that $k = n = 12$.  So indeed, the nullspace is a subspace of $\Bbb R^{12}$.

> **Is it possible to have rank = 4, dimension of null space = 8?**
>
> $rank \leq min(m,n)$ for $m \times n$ matrix,
>
> rank + nullity = number of columns.
>
> It is possible.
>
> **Is it possible to have rank = 8, dimension of null space = 4?**
>
> rank + nullity = number of columns
>
> but $rank \nleq min(m,n)$.
>
> It is not possible.

Both of these are correct; I have nothing to add.